# Why is my django model throwing an error?

Tags: python, django-models

I'm putting together a model for a blog app.

Here's the model:

```
from django.db import models

class Tag(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.keyword

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    image = models.ImageField
    body = models.TextField()
    visible = models.BooleanField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I added the blog package to settings.py. Then I ran `python manage.py sql blog`. I got the following errors:

```
 File "/pathto/blog/models.py", line 5, in Tag
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post)
NameError: name 'Post' is not defined
```

I don't understand why Post is not defined because I am defining it in the models.py file. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem

When you are defining `Tag` class, `Post` class is not yet defined. Because you are referring to it, you get `NameError` exception.

### Solution

Thus, change this line:

```
posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post)
```

into this line:

```
posts = models.ManyToManyField('Post')
```

### Explanation

[The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) gives you walkaround:

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself:
>
> ```
> class Car(models.Model):
>     manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer')
>     # ...
>
> class Manufacturer(models.Model):
>     # ...
> ```

### Alternative solution

You can also omit definition of `posts` in `Tag` class (the line "`posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post)`") and just provide the appropriate name for reverse relation in `Post` model. Django will know what to do with it. Just replace this line:

```
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

with this line:

```
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='posts')
```

To learn more, read about [`related_name` argument when defining relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) (`ForeignKey` and `ManyToManyField`).

Comment: What? how does it know to look for Post when its a string?

Comment: @quakkels: When it is a string, the lookup is then handled by Django when it is needed. You may treat it as if it was "lazy" foreign key (meaning: not evaluated until needed). When you use `Post` as a reference, you hit the basic error in Python code: the variable named `Post` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

As answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618720/django-nameerror-during-manytomany-field-referencing), you have are referencing a model (Post) before you've actually defined it -- definition order in a Python file is significant.

To get around the problem, let Django resolve that name rather than Python, by enclosing it with single-quotes:

`posts = models.ManyToManyField('Post')`